# Why does a change of direction imply an acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

We know that it takes no energy to change the direction of a vector, we know also that it takes no energy to displace a body in motion if a push is applied exactly at a right angle on its center of mass.

Considering that, if that is true, can you explain why a simple change of direction without any increase of speed is considered an acceleration?

Comment: Your two premises seem false. Can you provide references for them?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, do you know the formula to calculate the energy required to change the direction of a vector? What force/energy do we need to change the direction of a body m = 1, v = 10 m/s by 1°, or 1rad?

Comment: As @RedGrittyBrick said, your premises aren't correct. If you apply a "push" you are exerting a force on the object, thus doing work, thus expending energy. It requires a force to change the direction of the trajectory of an object (in non-relativistic mechanics).  For example, a constant inward radial force is needed to keep a body in orbit with constant speed. The magnitude of the body's velocity is constant, while the direction is changing. But the presence of that force means it must be constantly accelerating.

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines, if my premise is not correct and you need force/work/energy to divert  a body B (m=1,v=10m/s) by 1 degree, how come nobody knows the formula to calculate it? Do you know how much work/joules is needed to change B's direction 1°?

Comment: I think people want you to work it out for yourself. Use Newton's second law.

Comment: I don't recommend approaching physics problems this way. It can be tempting to look for formulas that solve the exact problem at hand, and do the old "plug and chug". Try to resist that. You won't deepen your understanding with that approach, and it won't carry you through upper level physics. Now here are some hints: 1) you need to act with a force for a period of time in the direction in which you want to accelerate the body. 2) you need to "add" a horizontal component to the velocity (think about how this relates to the first hint). 3) your problem as stated has two unknowns (which two?)

Answer (score 3):

## Answer to the question in the title?

Two vectors are only equal to each other if they are *the same* (this is a general rule: equality means the things compared are identical). That means having the same direction as well as the same magnitude.

So how could changing the direction of motion *not* be acceleration?

Don't get hung up on fact that in 1 dimension acceleration always involved changing the magnitude, just ask if the final and initial velocities are the same or not.

## Comment on the body text

In the body you ask about kinetic energy. There are two issues that come up with that:

1. Kinetic energy (or any energy) is a scalar, and so it can remain the same while the velocity changes (as in uniform circular motion).
2. Changes in (or differences of) velocity are the same for all inertial observer, but changes in kinetic energy are not. If you are thinking of the work-energy theorem you'll notice that this makes the work done frame-dependent as well. But this is not a surprise because the length and direction of the path is frame-dependent.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify if my premise was wrong? What force/impulse/energy is needed to change the direction of motion of a body (m=1, v= 10m/s) by one degree or radian?

Comment: Impulse is the right quantity to ask about and it comes directly from the impulse-momentum theorem. $\vec{J} = \Delta \vec{p} = m \,\Delta \vec{v}$, so that $|J| \approx m |v| \sin\theta$ (where the approximation is good for small angles). But frankly I think that your problem is that you are treating works like "force" and "energy" as if your colloquial understanding of them is good enough rather than treating them as having precise meanings. You shouldn't be guessing at which concept applies, you should be able to *deduce* which one to use.

Comment: If I want to change the speed of B (M=1, v=10m/s), that is to increase it by 1m/s, I can use various means, "words" or "concepts", but it always boils down to giving 10.5 J, and an extra 1m/s will cost an additional 11.5. Now, if I want to change its direction by 1...2 degree[s], can I know in advance how much energy I have to spend ?

Comment: Notice that to an observer passing in a train moving at $10 \,\mathrm{m/s}$ you add $0.5\,\mathrm{J}$ to the mass, but still change it's velocity by $1\,\mathrm{m/s}$. (That is what I've written as (2) above.) The work done is not a frame-independent thing. The importance of invariance may take a while to get used to, but it deeply fundamental. There are frames in which any particular instantaneous change of direction of an orbiting satellite takes the form of a pure change in instantaneous speed: but that could be from stopped or to stopped so the KE change may have either sign.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes easier to understand if you think of velocity being made up of perpendicular components.

For example, let $v = v_x\hat i + v_y\hat j$.

That is, velocity is made up of an x-component, $v_x$ and a y-component, $v_y$.

When there is a change of direction, the $v_x$ and $v_y$ components will change.  This means there must be some horizontal acceleration and some vertical acceleration.  Overall the magnitude of the velocity might not change, but you will still need horizontal and vertical acceleration to change the values of $v_x$ and $v_y$ which is required for a change of direction.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly said:

1. A change of velocity $\mathbf{v}$ in time  means that $\frac{\textrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\textrm{d}t} \neq \mathbf{0}$
2. The acceleration $\mathbf{a}$ is defined as $\mathbf{a}=\frac{\textrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\textrm{d}t}$
3. Therefore $\mathbf{a} \neq \mathbf{0}$ or in words *if your velocity changes you will have an acceleration*. Velocity also changes when only its direction changes -> that is why this is considered an acceleration

Nowhere here do you have to apply any considerations about energy.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise about conservation of energy is correct: A change in direction does not require energy. The applied force and the direction of distance travelled are perpendicular, and thus the work applied W = **F.s** will be zero, since both vectors are perpendicular.

The acceleration is not zero, since there is deceleration in the x direction, and acceleration in the y direction.